# Setting up Iterated Integral to polar form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Setup the integral $$\iint_D f(x,y) \, dA$$ as an iterated integral in polar coordinates where $$D=\left\{ (x,y)\mid |x|\leq y \leq 3, -3\leq x \leq 3\right\}$$

So I got the integral $$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{|-3\sec\theta|}^{3\sqrt{2}} f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) r\,dr\,d\theta$$ Is this right? Do I still need to find $f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $D$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(3,3)$, and $(-3,3)$. So you should have $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$. For each such $\theta$, $r$ ranges from $0$ to whatever the value of $r$ is at the line $y=3$. To solve for this $r$ in terms of $\theta$, set $3=y=r\sin(\theta)$, so $r=3 \csc \theta$. The integral should be
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int_0^{3\csc\theta} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rdrd\theta.$$